# Google Chrome prompts web site to translate page content

Tags: google-chrome, radio-button

On a website i am working on, when ever i select a [radio-button](/questions/tagged/radio-button), Google Chrome asks to translate the page from Norwegian, even though the page is written in English. It does this from time to time and I'm not sure why. i have tried to load the page in fire fox and Internet Explorer but i do not see this problem there. Does [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome) have issues when using radio buttons, or could this be a problem in the code?

thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the html of the offending radio button?

Answer (score 1):

if you want so suppress google translate you can add the tag

```
<meta name="google" value="notranslate">
```

Or you can add the class notranslate to whichever item you don't want translated.

```
<span class="notranslate">
```

Comment: But why does Chrome alone think that the page is written in a different language?

Comment: i can't know unless you share the html

Comment: something tells me that it can't be the code because i just tested it on a different computer multiple times and never had the same issue come up

Comment: don't know Norwegian, how could it be in Norwegian then, any only think that it is on one computer and not another?

Comment: Sounds like you've got a Heisenberg on your hands! It's almost certainly your HTML though, because I've never had that happen on any website. Do you have any dynamically created content, also make sure all Chrome plugins are disabled.

Comment: It could THINK it's norwegian based on an improperly escaped HTML character or a unicode character like an accent mark. Impossible to know without the HTML though.